# How to write a binary file filled with zeros as binary digits?

Tags: python, binary

How can I write a binary file filled with zeros as binary digits?

For example I have 8 bits of zeros like 00000000 which will be saved as one byte.

Comment: Just write `\x00` characters.

Comment: And to explain, the \xXX syntax is hexadecimal notation of the actual byte value of the character, so that \x00 is a byte with the value 0, and \x0F would be the value 15.

Answer (score 9):

Files are sequences of bytes, and Python trivially lets you write bytes. Just write `\x00` characters to produce byes that consist of nothing but `0` bits.

Open the file as binary and just write as many such bytes as you need:

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as binfile:
    binfile.write(b'\x00' * desired_length)
```